# How to define a template class which it can owns arbitrary parameters?

Tags: c++, templates

this question comes about when I was reading C++ Obj model,chapter 1.give an example that I can't understand.

The author want to define a template class that both type and the number of coordinate can be controlled.

Here is the code:

```
template < class type, int dim >
class Point
{
public:
   Point();
   Point( type coords[ dim ] ) {
      for ( int index = 0; index < dim; index++ )
         _coords[ index ] = coords[ index ];
   }
   type& operator[]( int index ) {
      assert( index < dim && index >= 0 );
      return _coords[ index ]; }
   type operator[]( int index ) const
      {   /* same as non-const instance */   }
   // ... etc ...
private:
   type _coords[ dim ];
};
inline
template < class type, int dim >
ostream&
operator<<( ostream &os, const Point< type, dim > &pt )
{
   os << "( ";
   for ( int ix = 0; ix < dim-1; ix++ )
      os << pt[ ix ] << ", ";
   os << pt[ dim-1 ];
   os << " )";
}
```

what does `index < dim && index >= 0`  means? index is a container like vector?

why did he override the operator?

Comment: It checks that `index` is less than `dim` and greater than or equal to `0`. The operator is overriden so you can access elements as you would with an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what does `index < dim && index >= 0` means?

It evaluates to `true` if `index` is less than `dim` and greater than or equal to zero.

> index is a container like vector?

No, it's an integer being used as an index into the array, `_coords`. Valid indexes are 0, 1, ..., `dim-1`, so the assertion checks that `index` is in that range.

> why did he override the operator?

So you can use `[]` to access the components of the point, as if it were itself an array.

```
Point<float, 3> point; // A three-dimensional point
float x = point[0];    // The first component
float y = point[1];    // The second component
float z = point[2];    // The third component
float q = point[3];    // ERROR: there is no fourth component
```

Each of those calls the overloaded operator. The last one will make the assertion fail; specifically, `index` will be 3, `dim` will also be 3, so `index < dim` will be false.